# Roles and Permissions Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, permissions, roles

I am a little bit confused with how to grant permissions depending on the user that it's logged in. On my Users table I have a field called "position", which they will be able to choose when they are registering This roles are saved as well in the db. Now I want that depending on their role, I get different layouts and different contents, for example, in my case I don't want the secretary to be able to see the expenses table and information. So in reality, I will have only the administrator and the secretary as roles, I tried to just check for the role but it's not working.

```
@if(Auth::user->role() == 'admin')
@extends('layouts.expenses')
@endif
```

I have seen several examples where there is need to install new dependencies to laravel like the "Entrust" one, but I don't know if there is something easier since my project it's already done, I am just missing this. I would gladly appreciate any advice or help that you can gave me. Thank you

Comment: You mean to do this `Auth::user()->position == 'admin'` ?

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, but it isn't working for me, I don't know if I have to add something else to the User model or something?

Comment: Can you show a dump of what `Auth::user()->position` produces? I have a suspicion that it returns a model and you need to access the property for that model before doing the comparison.

Comment: It's giving me this error:
ErrorException in 7f376ebc3e982767e2643bb688c12c7342172119.php line 1:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) (View: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sanvicente/CasaHogarSanVicente/resources/views/finanzas/gastos/index.blade.php)

Comment: This is my User Model:
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;


   protected $table = 'users';
   
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
     
    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $fillable = [
         'first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name', 'address', 'email', 'phone', 'position', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}

Comment: I was able to do it! I didn't write it correctly. It was like this: @if(Auth::user()->position == 'Administrador')